# как сделать такие же линии используя css и html

Tags: html, css

помогите сделать эту часть макета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую часть? Где скрин хотя бы?

Comment: нижнюю можно сделать как просто div или hr. Верхние линии через псевдоэлемент ::after и ::before

Comment: можно кодом,а то я пока делитант

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существуют теги `fieldset` - `legend`:

```css
body { background-color: #ebebeb; }
.main {
  border: 1px solid #123;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  color: #4f4d6a;
  text-align: center;
}
.main legend {
  margin: auto;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.main div { font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<fieldset class="main">
  <legend>CHECK OUT</legend>
  <div>OUR WORK</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```css
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #4f4d6a;
}

.text > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text .small {
  column-gap: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
}

.text .big {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text .small::before,
.text .small::after,
.text::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="small">check out</div>
  <div class="big">our worx</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.title {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4f4d6a;
}

.title p {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ebebeb;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.title h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <p>CHECK OUT</p>
  <h2>OUR WORX</h2>
</div>
```